# jQuery Animation: Stop Animating Once Mouse Out

Tags: jquery, animation

I am trying to make a `div` to slide out and in upon hover i.e. mouse enter and leave, respectively. However, when I hovered in and out several times, the `div` kept sliding back and forth basically up to the number of times I did the hover. Please refer to this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sikusikucom/TQz5U/).

As you've probably guessed, I am hoping to make the `div` stop (i.e. slided in) once the mouse is outside of the element regardless how many times I've moused over it. I think there is something missing in my understanding about jQuery animation.

```
$("#state-slider").hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    left: '0'
  }, 500);
}, function() {
  $(this).animate({ left: "-270" }, 500);
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need the [jQuery `.stop()` function](http://api.jquery.com/stop/). Insert it in your command chain before you start a new animation, to interrupt any ongoing animations.

```
$('#state-slider').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ left: 0 }, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ left: -270 }, 500);
});
```

[Working jsFiddle =)](http://jsfiddle.net/TQz5U/2/)

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you! Do you know why we also need `.stop()` upon mouse enter? I know we need to have it because otherwise there will be a "jump" like in @3nigma's answer; however, I am not sure the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @Siku-Siku.Com: The reason for using `.stop()` on both mouse-enter and mouse-leave becomes apparent if you hover your mouse over the div, move it away and then quickly back again. What the user expects from that is the div to "turn around", i.e. *stop what it was doing and do the new thing instead*. That's precisely what `.stop()` does.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#state-slider").hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    left: '0'
  }, 500);
}, function() {
  $(this).stop(true,true).animate({ left: "-270" }, 500);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TQz5U/3/)

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Thank you, @3nigma. However, note that there is a "jump" when you mouse enter the `div` and immediately out. I think we also need to `.stop()` upon mouse enter?

Comment: Ah, I got it now: to prevent the "jump," use `stop(true)` instead of `stop(true, true)`.

Answer (score 0):

there is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/TQz5U/1/

and jquery code

```
$(function() {
    $("#state-slider").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
            left: '0'
        }, 500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop(true,true).animate({ left: "-270" }, 500);
    });
});
```